# How to load info from another FILE in python

Tags: python, file, import, repeat, getopenfilename

I want to run something from another file that I created but it is repeating the first part of the code.
Please comment/respond respectfully :)

```
from replit import clear
from time import sleep
import pickle
playername= input("Enter your username: ")
sleep(1.0)
pickle.dump(playername, open(playername, "wb"))

clear()
import gamemenu.py
gamemenu.py = open(gamemenu.py, open(gamemenu.py))
```

my output is

```
Enter your username:
```

*enters username*

```
Enter your username:
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the contents of *gamemenu.py*. You should also explain what you are trying to run from that file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the rest of your code, but this looks wrong:

`gamemenu.py = open(gamemenu.py, open(gamemenu.py))`